# find specific tag and replace all fields under it in perl

Tags: regex, linux, perl, find

i have a file like following contents

```
[amrit]
type=friend
host=111.118.253.145
port=2776
username=amrit
secret=password
disallow=all
allow=gsm
context=sip-calling
qualify=yes
call-limit=22

[windwos]
type=friend
host=111.118.253.145
port=2775
username=amrit
secret=password
disallow=all
allow=gsm
context=sip-calling
qualify=yes
call-limit=50


[windwos121254]
type=friend
host=111.118.253.145
port=2776
username=amrit
secret=password
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
context=sip-calling
qualify=yes
call-limit=99
```

now i want to create a script in perl. that will find all  all lines under [amrit] this tag

```
type=friend
host=111.118.253.145
port=2776
username=amrit
secret=password
disallow=all
allow=gsm
context=sip-calling
qualify=yes
call-limit=22
```

now i want to update the value of each field but values should be change of this tag only i have find the these line using a perl script but i am not able to change the value of these fileds. Script is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$count = 0;
open (IN, "file.txt");
while (<IN>) {
    if (/\[amrit\]/) {
    $count = 1;
    }
    elsif (/\[*\]/) {
    $count = 0;
    }
    elsif ($count) {
    print;
      }
}
close IN;
```

Now i want to update the value of each line that are in [amrit] tag. i am a beginner in perl please help me here.

Comment: If that is an INI file, you can use [`Config::INI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3A%3AINI).

Comment: well, all your values have to change or some special tag?

Comment: @TLP it is a conf file

Comment: @JackXu now i want to change the value of each line under [amrit] tag.

Comment: what about `Config::Tiny`?

Comment: I really dont know how to use this module . m trying to work by it.

Comment: @user2916639 ok i have posted answer using same please look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Config::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Config%3a%3aTiny) is here for what you want.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

    use strict;
    use Config::Tiny;

    my $config = Config::Tiny->read('test.ini');

    my $section ="amrit";

    print "[$section]\n";
    foreach my $parameter (keys %{$config->{$section}}) 
    {
        print "\t$parameter = $config->{$section}->{$parameter}\n"; 
    }
```

Here is script for reading specific tag data.

You can set value by this

```
 $Config->{section}->{username} = 'No user';     # Change a value
```

Also more usefull api as below

```
  # Changing data
    $Config->{newsection} = { this => 'that' }; # Add a section
    $Config->{section}->{Foo} = 'Not Bar!';     # Change a value
    delete $Config->{_};                        # Delete a value or section
```

Comment: Why do you use a `for` loop over the sections? If you removed the `for` loop and the `if` statement, and replaced them with `my $section = 'amrit';` it would be faster and clearer.

Comment: How i get section name without for...loop?

Comment: If you know batter solution then please edit my answer.thanks in advance.

Comment: You already know that the section name is `amrit`. You even make sure that it is the same with the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Using `AppConfig`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use AppConfig qw/:argcount/;
use Data::Dumper;

my $config = AppConfig->new( { CREATE => 1, GLOBAL => { ARGCOUNT => ARGCOUNT_ONE } } );
   $config->file( \*DATA );

my %amrit = $config->varlist( '^amrit_' );
print Dumper \%amrit;

print $config->get( 'amrit_type' ), "\n";
      $config->set( 'amrit_type', 'enemy' );
print $config->get( 'amrit_type' ), "\n";

__DATA__
[amrit]
type=friend
host=111.118.253.145
port=2776
username=amrit
secret=password
disallow=all
allow=gsm
context=sip-calling
qualify=yes
call-limit=22

[windwos]
type=friend
host=111.118.253.145
port=2775
username=amrit
secret=password
disallow=all
allow=gsm
context=sip-calling
qualify=yes
call-limit=50


[windwos121254]
type=friend
host=111.118.253.145
port=2776
username=amrit
secret=password
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
context=sip-calling
qualify=yes
call-limit=99
```

Comment: If you need to write to the config file itself, although possible, it is fiddly with AppConfig. Config::INI, as suggested by TLP, would be preferred.